# django raw sql query does not return data

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is my sample model

and this is my view

```
def index(request):
    fetch_post_data = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-created_date')[:5]
    fetch_pgraph_data = Post.objects.raw("select count(title) as uno,published_date from blog_post group by DATE(published_date)")
    #fetch_pgraph_data = Post.objects.raw("select * from blog_post")
    template_var = {'postodj':fetch_post_data,'userdataobj':fetch_pgraph_data}
    return render(request,'home.html',context=template_var)
```

when I am trying to fetch the data using fetch_pgraph_data, it's showing Raw query must include the primary key

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `raw` queries must include the primary key. This is because they generate model instances, and the key is required in order to do things like fetching other deferred attributes.

But I don't think you need a raw query here at all. You can easily produce this query via standard ORM methods:

```
Post.objects.values('published_date').annotate(Count('title'))
```

Comment: as of now it's working. But if I want to execute raw sql queries need to define primary key in model ? Actually I need to compare two table table, but there are no foreign key relation.